# Use of ng-infinite-scroll-min.js in asp.net mvc application throwing error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please help me with this issue , I've searched a lot but haven't came across any solution

used below code to include  `ng-infinite-scroll-min.js`

```
var app = angular.module("ngModuleJobTapPagination", ['infinite-scroll']);
```

Comment: Please post your code to jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: Hi wow, I am having this exact same problem.  Just so you know I have gotten infinite scroll working on another branch of my project.  I am trying to get it working on a different branch and have encountered this problem. I hope we find a solution!